# How to Deploy .NETCore App to Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, service, deployment, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have been trying to deploy to Azure Service Fabric an app built with .NETCore Standard Library 1.6. We are using a bunch of new libraries we ported from .NET 4.5.2 framework to .NET Core 1.0.
I could not find any help.

Answer (score 3):

I worked it out and it is really simple. You must "publish" your .NETCoreApp to an output folder such as bin/release using the "File System" as the publish target.
Then create your Service Fabric project to use the "guest executable" template. Browse to your publish folder as the CodePackage source.
If your are still developing your .NETCoreApp use the link to the package selection.
Finally you must remember to republish your app every time you wish to test your code in the fabric before you publish to the fabric.
For more details see my [blog](https://laultman.wordpress.com/2016/10/01/deploy-netcoreapp-to-azure-service-fabric/).
Hope this helps.